# How to get the path of image android?

Tags: android, android-studio

I am selecting an image of the gallery from my app,
using

> ACTION_GET_CONTENT

Now I want the path of this image:

[image]

But i get it like this:

> content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A5793

How can i get the path?

I tried this to get path:

```
Uri uri = data.getData();
Log.e("Path is: "+uri);
```

Answer (score 4):

The answer is don't try and get the path because in Android 10 and later you won't be able to get it or use it.

You can get a `FileDescriptor` or input/output Stream that can be used in most methods that need to access the file contents.

See https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/ for more details, since it is a picture then using Media store is probably best.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
Uri uri = data.getData();
        String picturePath = getPath( getActivity( ).getApplicationContext( ), uri);
        Log.e("Picture Path", picturePath);

public static String getPath( Context context, Uri uri ) {
    String result = null;
    String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver( ).query( uri, proj, null, null, null );
    if(cursor != null){
        if ( cursor.moveToFirst( ) ) {
            int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow( proj[0] );
            result = cursor.getString( column_index );
        }
        cursor.close( );
    }
    if(result == null) {
        result = "Not found";
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: I am getting Log as - Path is:: 5809

Comment: On Android 10 this could will always return "Not found" as Data column is deprecated https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.MediaColumns#DATA