# Now that we cannot use the File API on Android any idea on how to append an existing file?

Tags: android

I'm trying to replace the File API I was using in my app as Google now forces us to use other APIs. I tried to use DocumentFile to ask for access to storage on the device so I can download files there. However, I cannot find how to append existing files.
Up until now I was using the FileWriter API for this. Any idea about how I can no append content to existing files?
Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the path of image android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60316536/how-to-get-the-path-of-image-android)

Comment: The FileWriter API accepts a FileDescriptor which you can get via SAF

Comment: You should open the file in append mode.

Comment: @blackapps which is basically what I'm asking here... How can I do that?

Comment: @Andrew sorry but this other post isn't related to my question

Comment: At opening the file one would add a parameter "wt".